# PySpark & MLLib: random forest prediction result always 0

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, random-forest

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'main.csv', header=0)
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("myapp") \
    .getOrCreate()
s_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
transformed_df = s_df.rdd.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row[0], Vectors.dense(row[1:])))

splits = [0.7, 0.3]
training_data, test_data = transformed_df.randomSplit(splits, 100)
model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(training_data, numClasses=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo={},
                                 numTrees=3, featureSubsetStrategy="auto",
                                 impurity='gini', maxDepth=4, maxBins=32)

predictions = model.predict(test_data.map(lambda x: x.features))
```

when print test_data.map(lambda x: x.features) the result is

```
[DenseVector([1431500000.0, 9.3347, 79.8337, 44.6364, 194.0, 853.0, 196.9998]),
 DenseVector([1431553600.0, 9.5484, 80.7409, 39.5968, 78.0, 923.0, 196.9994])....]
```

numbers inside the `DenseVector([numbers])` are correct for prediction

but the result of the prediction is 0

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0...]
```

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing your data; are you sure you don't have a class imbalance issue, i.e. *much more* 0's than 1's in your initial `df`?

Comment: I used dummy data in this model, there is no 0 in the original data set

Comment: You mean, you get `0.0` as prediction, but there is no `0.0` in your original labels??

Comment: Yes. Do you know what could cause the result to be 0?